# Getting API resolved without sending a response error even when sending response

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, formidable

I am trying to send `res.json` after I successfully save data in database and save the upload the image but I am constantly getting `API resolved without sending a response for /api/auth/registeration, this may result in stalled requests.`. Also I am using formidable for image upload in Next.js.

**code:**

```
import connection from "../../../utils/connection/getConnection";
import formidable from "formidable";
const signupSchema = require("../../../models/signup");
import mkdirp from "mkdirp";
import bcrpt, { genSaltSync } from "bcrypt";
import fs from "fs";
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const handlePost = async (req, res) => {
  const form = formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, async function (err, field, files) {
    await fileSavour(field, files);
    return res.json({
      message: "success",
    });
  });
};

const fileSavour = async (fields, files) => {
  let { email, password } = fields;
  let imageName = files.image.name;

  let newPassword = await bcrpt.hash(password, genSaltSync(10));

  const newUser = new signupSchema({
    email,
    password: newPassword,
    image: imageName,
  });

  const Nuser = await newUser.save();

  if (Nuser) {
    await mkdirp("public/profileImages/" + Nuser._id);

    if (imageName) {
      const data = fs.readFileSync(files.image.path);

      const pathToSave = "public/profileImages/" + Nuser._id + "/" + imageName;

      fs.writeFileSync(pathToSave, data);
      await fs.unlinkSync(files.image.path);
      return;
    }
  }
};

const Register = async (req, res) => {
  req.method === "POST"
    ? handlePost(req, res)
    : req.method === "PUT"
    ? console.log("PUT")
    : req.method === "DELETE"
    ? console.log("DELETE")
    : req.method === "GET"
    ? console.log("GET")
    : res.status(404).send("");
};

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `handlePost` handler function will not wait for the `form.parse` callback to execute (and subsequently for `res.json` to be called), and will return immediately. To prevent this, you can wrap the `form.parse` with a Promise to ensure the handler waits for the callback function to execute.

```js
const handlePost = async (req, res) => {
    const form = formidable.IncomingForm();
    
    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        form.parse(req, async function(err, fields, files) {
            await fileSavour(field, files);
            resolve();
        });
    });

    res.json({ message: "success" });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to promisify the `form.parse` function. Currently, your request is returned before the form is parsed.

Let's define a function which promisifies the form parse using `formidable`, and use it to parse all the requests. The function should look like this -

```js
const promisifiedParseForm = (req) => {
   const form = formidable.IncomingForm();
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      form.parse(req, function (err, field, files) {
         if (err) {
            reject(err)
         } else {
            resolve({ field, files })
         }
      });
   });
}
```

Use the `promisifiedParseForm` function in the `handlePost` function, like this -

```js
const handlePost = async (req, res) => {
   const { field, files } = await promisifiedParseForm(req);
   
   await fileSavour(field, files);

   return res.json({
      message: "success",
   });
};
```